# What are some use cases of discrete optimization in Deep Learning?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization

When we talk of optimization, it usually boils down to gradient descent and its variants in the context of deep learning. However, I wonder if there are some works that use discrete optimization in one way or another in deep learning.

In brief, what are some applications of discrete optimization to deep learning?